# Which Advanced 3D design software can be used for woodworking?

Tags: design

As per the title, which advanced 3D modeling software can be used for designing projects/pieces?

For the moment I am using Sketchup Free but it is lacking in the complex shapes, i.e. compound cuts, as well as measuring angles and copying them easily; therefore, I am thinking about upgrading to the shop version which costs 120/yr or finding something else more advanced.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. I've edited the title and wording of your Question to bring it more into line with what's expected on SE. Please see [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) in the Help.... as you can see the first two bullets applied to your Q as originally worded.

Comment: See: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=woodworking

Answer (score 2):

As you've used SketchUp, you've experienced the effort involved in dragging out shapes/lines/etc and ensuring dimensions for your project.

A 3D modeling program, web-based and free that may do as you require is Tinkercad. It allows one to drop primitives (box, sphere, cone, etc) onto a workplane and manipulate them as needed to create the project.

All of the basic operations such as move/translate, rotate, etc are graphically represented and easily understood. There are a few features of note, such as workplane, which allows one to create a new reference based on an existing object.

Due to the low overhead of the software, it's relatively fast to "toss out the shapes" on the workplane and push them around to get a good view of the project, then use the fine-tuning features to place them precisely.

The default setting is metric, but can be changed to Imperial units if desired.

As an example, I downloaded a laser cut project, provided free, without instructions for assembly. It was a rather complex set of parts and not intuitive, especially for the gift recipient. I was able to load the cut file's individual pieces into tinkercad and manipulate them to determine placement and fit, without having to cut a single piece of wood.

Once the basics are learned, it's a fairly intuitive program.

You've not noted if you require a specific output format and anything other than a visual representation may require other software, which isn't necessarily a problem.

The image below is of a recent project, with the components created and assembled in Tinkercad. It allowed me to determine placement of the panels with respect to a reference figure in the center. The dimensions are to scale and used to create the complete project using other software.

[image: example box]

Comment: Tinker-cad is not as advanced as sketch up in the shape department which is needed for my particular situation.

Comment: @CadeWaren, could you specify your particular situation then, to help direct focus more towards something that *would* suit? You haven't for example listed where you find the free version of Sketchup is lacking, perhaps that would be a start. As the Question stands this Answer seems to tick all the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I user Blender, woodworking wasn't the primary thought when designing the software but it works really well. There can be a bit of a steep learning curve though.

Comment: Could you expand on this to provide more info, screenshots etc. to make it a more fully fleshed Answer? That would help the OP and any future readers interested in the same topic. SE favours long, not short Answers, with as much key detail contained within the Answer itself and not hosted externally as practical, so as to make it a standalone reference, and to prevent it becoming useless in case any URLs change in the future.

Comment: "steep learning curve" is the understatement of the year for Blender.